# getting index of outer array if there's a match in inner array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

when i `print_r` my array gives

```
Array ( 
   [0] => Array ( [userid] => 2 [popularity] => 41.7 ) 
   [1] => Array ( [userid] => 5 [popularity] => 33.3 ) 
   [2] => Array ( [userid] => 7 [popularity] => 25.0 ) 
)
```

is the array returned after querying users and sort by popularity desc, meaning

user with `id 2 has popularity 41.7`, 
user with `id 5 has popularity 33.3` and so on,

Then i have a dynamic query that shows each user with his popularity
example: 
`user with id 2 has popularity of 41.7`
                `user with id 5 has popularity of 33.3` etc.

All i want is to show the position(outer array `index`) of each user if user id of dynamic query matches the output of array above then increment by 1 because array index always starts 0
example: 
`user with id 2, will have position of 1 (the winner)`

 `user with id 5, will have position of 2`
        
`user with id 7, will have position of 3` etc..

how can i do that...

Comment: what code have you already tried?

Comment: i have this function:  function search_exif($exif, $field)
{
    foreach ($exif as $data)
    {
        if ($data['label'] == $field)
            return $data['raw']['_content'];
    }
}; $camera = search_exif($exif['photo']['exif'], 'model');   then i can search for match, but i am stuck how what can i do

Comment: Please do not post additional information as comments here. It is not readable. There is an `edit` button below your question...

Comment: Take a look at the various array functions documented on php.net: http://php.net/manual/de/array.sorting.php Amongst it are functions to sort an array by elements of its content which is what you want. There are many many example alone here on SO and many more millions out on google.

Comment: Why you can't do `$key+1` inside `foreach ($array as $key => $value) {` ?

Answer (score 2):

This code modifies array and ads new key 'position' (= $key + 1) to each element.

```
function addPosition(&$item, $key) {
    $item['position'] = $key + 1;
}
array_walk($data, 'addPosition');
```